# html относительные ссылки с другого сайта

Tags: html

Какой тег задает пути для относительных ссылок?

Есть ссылка вида `/css/main.css`, этот файл находится на сайте `site1.ru`, как на странице сайта `site2.ru` заставить считать все относительные ссылки, ссылками с сайта `site1.ru` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

За это отвечает тег base:

На странице сайта `site2.ru` пишем:

```
<base href="http://site1.ru/">
```